# CheckBox click not working if it is inside a div having a click event

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a situation where check box check event is not working. I have placed the check-box inside a div which has click event and on that I check/uncheck the check-box.

```
<div onclick="checkCheckBox('ch_0')">
    <input type='checkbox' value='20' id='ch_0'/>
</div>
```

and written the script as follows

```
 function checkCheckBox(checkboxId)
 {
     var checkBoxes = $("#" + checkboxId);
        checkBoxes.attr("checked", !checkBoxes.attr("checked"));
        if (checkBoxes.attr("checked") == true) {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
 }
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle? So tat we will know what you have tried

Comment: Are you doing this so that any text within the div, when clicked, causes the checkbox to become 'checked' ?

Comment: @PatDobson yes anywhere in the div.

Comment: You should use < label for="checkboxName" > element instead of div because when you click on the label it is automatically linked to the checkbox and will check/uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: @vyx.ca I have some text and images inside my div also

Answer (score 6):

This behaviour is exactly what the `label` element was intended for; there is no need for javascript:

```
<label>
    <input type='checkbox' value='20' id='ch_0'/>
     Foo Bar Checkbox
</label>
```

If you check in **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/5Rb79/)** you'll see the hit area for the checkbox is the entire `label` element, which is expanded to include the text.

Comment: Yes, thats true, but his checkbox will still be not clickable, only label will be clickable and works. He has to position absolute his checkbox, to has checkbox (not only label) clickable.

Comment: thanks but I have images and some other text also inside the div including the checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

It is working, you might have problem somewhere else

**[live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g7TVS/)**

```
function checkCheckBox(id)
{
    alert(id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function checkCheckBox(id)
 {
      $("div input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",true)
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you click on input, you should stopPropagation, like that, it don't propagate to the parent div.

```
$('#mydiv').on('click',function(){
        alert('in the div');
    });

    $('#myinput').on('click',function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();             <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        alert('in the input');
    });
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/UCR5q/

Answer (score 1):

Try using prop like this

```
function checkCheckBox(checkboxId) {
    var that = $('#' + checkboxId);
    var checked = that.prop('checked');
    that.prop('checked', !checked)
    .parent()
    .toggleClass('selected');
}
```

You are using `this` to get the div, but you havn't passed this in the function so you must use .parent()

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/jXheH/2/)

Or you can use .onclick function like this

```
    $('#myDiv').on('click', function () {
        var chk = $(this).find('input');
        var toggleChck = chk.prop('checked');
        chk.prop('checked', !toggleChck);
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/jXheH/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.prop` instead of `.attr`.

```
$('div').on('click',function(){
  var isChecked = $($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]')[0]).prop('checked');
  if(isChecked){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  }
  else{
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
  }
});
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sHkjc/)

Answer (score 1):

To make your CheckBox click working if it is inside a div having a click event, you can probably try this on your checkbox which click event is currently not working :

CSS :

```
div input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable the text to check the checkbox, you must give the label a 'for' attribute:

```
<label for='ch_0'>Click here to check me</label>
<input type='checkbox' value='20' name='ch_0' id='ch_0'/>
```

In this way, clicking *either* the checkbox or the label will check the checkbox.

(It's also worth adding the 'name' attribute to the input to 'tie' it semantically to the label)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3c52/):

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hungry"/>
    <img src="http://samstavernseattle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Magic-Mushroom-Burger.jpg" width="50" alt="" />
    <span>FOOOD</span>
</label>
```

It passes the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) too.